# Trying to use a variable after ctx.fillText with Canvas. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm trying to use a function to generate letters, which will appear at a particular location on the canvas. I put notes in the code below to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {  ////THIS FUNCTION GENERATES ONE OF 3 LETTERS
    function WordSelector1() {
      var word = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
      var random = word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)];
      return random;
      // [enter image description here][1]
    }

    var x = WordSelector1();  ////AND ASSIGNS THOSE LETTERS AS VARIABLE "X"

    $('#x').html(x);  ////ANY TIME THE ID "X" APPEARS,
    //// IT SHOULD GET REPLACED WITH THE VARIABLE AND, IN TURN, A LETTER
});

function init() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  draw(ctx);
}

function draw(ctx) {
  // layer1/Line
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(15.1, 7.7);
  ctx.lineTo(92.9, 7.2);
  ctx.stroke();

  // layer1/P
  ctx.font = "16.0px 'Myriad Pro'";
  ctx.fillText("x", -0.0, 10.0);   ////VARIABLE ISN'T CORRECTLY REPLACING THIS ID. 
////IN OTHER WORDS, A LETTER IS NOT APPEARING AT THIS LOCATION
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="93" height="14"></canvas>
<br><br>
<span id="x"></span> & <span id="xx"></span> & <span id="xxx"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#x')` do not select every elements with and id that starts with 'x'. It selects *the* element (because ids are unique) that has the exact id 'x'.

Also, `init` and `draw` are never called in your code, and the canvas is useless. The first letter appears because you replace the content of the first span when you do `$('#x').html(x);`. But that is unrelated to the canvas.

About this line:
`ctx.fillText("x", -0.0, 10.0);`:
there is no variable involved. `"x"` is a string. If you are trying to access the `x` variable, this is written: `ctx.fillText(x, -0.0, 10.0);`. But that won't work here because `x` is not defined inside the `draw` function.

Is this what you are trying to do ?

```js
function WordSelector1() {
  var word = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  var random = word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)];
  return random;
}

function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  draw(ctx);
}

function draw(ctx) {
  // layer1/Line
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(15.1, 7.7);
  ctx.lineTo(92.9, 7.2);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  // layer1/P
  var x = WordSelector1();
  ctx.font = "16.0px 'Myriad Pro'";
  ctx.fillText(x, -0.0, 10.0);
  ctx.restore();
}

$(document).ready(init);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="93" height="14"></canvas>
```

Comment: Good point. I eliminated all other instances of id="x" but it still doesn't work.  The canvas functions fine except for the replacement of that variable. Is the ordering of my script off?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do (and I don't seen any change in your question). I edited my answer to suggest you a piece of code. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Nope, those spans are for something else. I shouldn't have even included them. I'm trying to have the "x" here: ctx.fillText("x", -0.0, 10.0) get replaced by a letter, so that a letter appears at this point on the canvas. I tried to replace the bit of code that you modified but it didn't change anything, unfortunately. That's not the problem - it has something to do with the ctx.fillText not picking up on that id replacement command.

Comment: YES! You're awesome. The only problem is that when you refresh on Jsfiddle, sometimes 2 variables appear overlaid. Is that a glitch specific to JSFiddle? I really appreciate your taking the time to help me.

Comment: "2 variables appear overlaid". That does not make much sense to me. What do you mean?

Comment: For example, both an A and a B will appear at the same time when the page is refreshed.

Comment: This does not happen here, so I think this is a behavior that happens because of code not present in this snippet. Are you sure you are not calling `draw` or `init` twice?

Comment: I think it was calling the init twice. Much appreciated.

Comment: A and B are not variables by the way. `x` is a variable. `"x"` is a string (that might be assigned to a variable, or not). In your case, when you're talking about A, I think you are talking about a bunch of pixels drawn on a canvas in the form of a 'A' shape.

Comment: Yeah, I was colloquially using the term "variables" in the algebraic sense. Thanks, again!

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid those comments have left no clear doubt. In all cases:

If what you expect and have the letter drawn in the exact location indicated on the screen

Old Code:

```
ctx.fillText(x, -0.0, 10.0);
```

New Code:

```
ctx.fillText($('#x').html(), -0.0, 10.0);
```